# Selenium Hub Exception with JsonPrimitive.isPrimitiveOrString

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

Instance of Selenium standalone server the node returns a 500 Error response NullPointerException raised at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.isPrimitiveOrString

Any tips to troubleshooting this error are apreciated.

Start the Selenium Server Hub and Node 
Check that the node is listed on the server console.

Software version:

- Apache Maven 3.5.0
- selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0
- ChromeDriver 2.31 - geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64
- Chrome v 60.0.3112.101 (64-bit)
- Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit)
- Java 1.8.0_92 (64-bit)

Server startup command:

```
java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar" -role hub 
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:/selenium/geckodriver.exe" -jar "selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Maven POM:

```
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
<scope>test</scope>

<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
```

Java Class (imports excluded):

```
public class GoogleSearchTest extends TestCase {
public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com/");    
}     }
```

Error stack:

```
Problem accessing /wd/hub/session. Reason:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException **    at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.isPrimitiveOrString(JsonPrimitive.java:278)
at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.setValue(JsonPrimitive.java:101)
at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.&lt;init&gt;(JsonPrimitive.java:65)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ExceptionHandler.lambda$execute$0(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
```

This error appears to occur very early in the automation test. Questions i don't yet have the answer to: What would be the JSON payload that is sent, Are there additional Capabilities that i need to configure.

Similar Post